# Casting Error I got when parsing data from SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

My database design is like that:

```
Column Name: ID ,Data Type: int
Column Name: No1 ,Data Type: float
Column Name: No2 ,Data Type: float
```

My database  entries are like that:

```
ID      No1         No2
1    64.25656     24.54465    
2    64.25656     24.54465
3    64.25656     24.54465
```

My code is like that:

```
public class JobInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public float No1 { get; set; }
    public float No2 { get; set; }
}

public class JobInfoRepository
{           
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        return reader.Cast<System.Data.IDataRecord>()
                     .Select(x => new JobInfo()
                     {
                         ID = x.GetInt32(0),
                         No1 = x.GetFloat(1),
                         No2 = x.GetFloat(2),
                     }).ToList();
    }
 }
```

Note:

I got

> InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code: Specified cast is not valid.

when I cast at the end of the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "at the end of the code"? Please give the full stack trace. Note that currently your code wouldn't even compile - you haven't declared a method to return from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consult the [SQL/C# type correspondence chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) and notice that TSQL's `float` corresponds to `System.Double`, not `System.Single` (aka `float` in C#).

Therefore, you should use `x.GetDouble` for `No1` and `No2`.